# Как String устроен внутри?

Tags: java

Пример:

```
String s = "cat";
s = s + "-" + s;
```

В примере который показывает как это работает "под капотом", я увидел следующее:

```
String s = "cat";
StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder(s);
s2.append("-");
s2.append(s);
s = s2.toString();
```

У меня несколько вопросов:
1. Пример который показывает как это работает под капотом, это правильный пример?

2. Как мне допустим самому посмотреть как работает это всё под капотом, просто этот пример получил на учебе

Comment: после компиляции получается bytecode - можно посмотреть в нем. В момент выполнения bytecode может использоваться JIT компиляция и конечный код может еще поменяться. В итоге "под капотом" может выполняться как приведенный код, так и просто `String s = "cat-cat";`

Comment: @Grundy я относительно начинающий и можете пожалуйста как-то вкратце поэтапно рассказать как это сделать, буду благодарен

Comment: Сделать что именно? Посмотреть bytecode? Для этого можно найти специальные инструменты

Comment: Во-первых, на сколько подробное объяснение вам нужно, как глубоко "под капот" вы хотите уйти? Во-вторых, для какой именно виртуальной машины и какой версии?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой способ это сделать тестовый класс и запустить всё это в дебаггере.
[Здесь](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/605-junit) Прям очень всё подробно расписано.
[Вот здесь](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/j3d_string.html) расписано про саму строку, а именно, что она неизменна. Следовательно, если вы что-то хотите к ней присоединить, то у вас создастся новый объект с новым значением, а не просто присоединится что-то.

То, что у вас выполнено тут

```
String s = "cat";
StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder(s);
s2.append("-");
s2.append(s);
s = s2.toString();
```

предподчтительней к использованию. У вас все объединения будут выполнены через `StringBuilder` ,а в  `s` запишется новое значение, которое будет указывать на другую ячейку памяти, аналогично и вашему изначальному примеру.

Comment: Не просто предпочтительней, это именно то, что будет выполнено при обычной конкатенации. Не помню с какой версии ввели эту фичу, но теперь не надо думать о проблеме конкатенации строк

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko, можете дать ссылку на источник, так сказать, повысить уровень знаний? Просто, я запустил через дебагер и там через AOP прошло в неведомые дали, но по факту знаю, что при конкатенации создается новый String

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/string-concatenation-performacne-improvement-in-ja Второй пример